# How To Detect Ctrl+V In AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Then, make `Xbutton1`act as <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a few seconds, but I can't get it working.

```
Transform, CtrlV, Chr, 3
Input, OutputVar, L1 M

XButton1::
    if OutputVar = CtrlV
    {
        SetTimer, SendEnter, 0
        Sleep, 2000
        SetTimer, SendEnter, Off
    }
    else
    {
        Send  ^t
    }
Return

SendEnter:
    Send {Enter}
Return
```

Comment: Why not just define a hotkey for it? `~^v::msgbox, you pressed CTRL+V` the tilde prefix keeps to original functionality.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but that's not what i want to do. :)

Comment: I think you're stuck in procedural thinking, but working with hotkeys is much more event-driven. You could, for instance, simply store the time when ctrl+v is pressed: `^v::lastPaste := A_TickCount`. Then, upon activation of `XButton1`, you can compare that time with the current time; or even nicer: Use `#If A_TickCount - lastPaste < 2000` to clearly lay out the different states. Are you sure that's not what you want to do? :)

Comment: Thanks for help! Your script is very simple, yet works perfectly! :)

Comment: Great! Please post your solution as an answer and accept it afterwards, so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~^v::lastPaste := A_TickCount ;stores counter when ctrl+v is pressed   
    Xbutton1::
        If A_TickCount - lastPaste < 2000 ;checks if 2 seconds gone after ctrl+v was clicked
        {
            Send, {Enter} ;sends enter
            Return
        }
        else
        {
            Send, ^t ;sends ctrl+t
            Return
        }
```

Comment: Where is CTRL+V? It would also be nice if you elaborated a bit on the solution.

Comment: Sorry didn't saw that i copied not all script :). Now its complete. Its really simple, i just did what you suggested.

Comment: @user3736903 No, you didn't. You only pasted entire code, but added no explanation. Even a tiny, one-line. And now your answer lands in very low quality queue and will probably be deleted, because of that. Please, reedit your question and add at least one line of explanation.

Comment: maybe bit better now? :)

Comment: **Here's what `~` means:** When AHK performs a script, it hides the key's regular function from the system. The `~` overrides that. So if you had a script like this: `^v::Return`, Ctrl+v wouldn't Paste anymore, it would do nothing. But, if the script had a tilde, like this: `~^v::Return` Paste would work normally.